# assign value to a varaible in onmessage in websocket

Tags: javascript, websocket

I try to assign a value to a variable in onmessage function here:

```
socket = new WebSocket(ws_scheme +"127.0.0.1:8000/chat/");
var incomeData;
socket.onmessage = function(e) {
     incomeData='hello'+ e.data; 
     console.log('inside function:'+incomeData)
}
socket.onopen = function() { 
    socket.send(" from websocket");
}
 console.log(incomeData)
```

the console will show the first log as undefined and the second  "inside function: hello from websocket". How can I get the variable assigned and keep the value outside the function too? Why second console.log appears first ?

Comment: onmessage is an asynchronous call so you can not assign value to the variable

Comment: What should I do if I want to  assign the e.data  to a variable, and use it as content in a web app?

Comment: pass a callback inside onmessage and then assign value

Answer (score 1):

`incomeData` is defined at global scope and is not assigned anything when first is printed with `console.log(incomeData)` thus you get the `undefined` error message. Then the socket `onmessage` is called and you got is assigned the `e.data` value that `console.log` then prints out.

You can handle the `socket.onmessage` and pass the `e.data` to a callback function like this:

```
socket = new WebSocket(ws_scheme +"127.0.0.1:8000/chat/");

socket.onmessage = function(e) {
    socket_onmessage_callback(e.data);
}

socket.onopen = function() { 
    socket.send(" from websocket");
}

function socket_onmessage_callback(data) {
    console.log('inside function socket_onmessage_callback:', data)
}
```

You can even use `incomeData` global variable if you want, but I think it does not required. Can update my answer if you need to use `incomeData`.

Comment: Assign incomeData to data in socket_onmessage_callback function, but outside the function global variable is still undefined.

Comment: @hln you can't have the `incomeData` filled with `e.data` there you have it on your code, because, as I wrote to my answer, this line of code executes **before** the `socket.onmessage` call. Can you see it makes total sense? You can't have this variable having the `e.data` assign to it because you print it out before the `WebSocket` actually receives any messages.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the main point of websocket protocol, you can easily update your global variables via a callback function which you pass to `websocket.onmessage` method of the protocol. The main point is that the backend server sends information to the client NOT in response to client's GETs or POSTs or whatever, but when it wants. There is no way to force a websocket endpoint to return you anything, it does it when it wants, even if you haven't asked for it. Once you have opened the `ws://` connection, get ready for receiving data through this connection ANY unexpected time. What you need to do is to make sure that your app won't crash on an initial (or an `undefined`) value of the variable to be assigned, and just let the server update your variable when the server (not you!) wants. Here is a working code example with a self-invoking `ws://` connection initialization (the `(function(...) {...})(...);` construction) and a callback:

```
<script>    
    var yourGlobalField = undefined;
    
    console.log("Value before update: ", yourGlobalField);

    (function initWebsocketConnection() {

        websocket = new WebSocket("ws://your.websocket.URI");

        websocket.onmessage = function (evt) {
            theFunctionNeededToMakeSureWeHaveReceivedRealData(evt, yourSuccessCallbackFunction(evt));
        };

        websocket.onerror = function(err) {
            networkError(err);
        }

    })();

    function theFunctionNeededToMakeSureWeHaveReceivedRealData(evt) {
        console.log("we have received some data!");
    }

    function yourSuccessCallbackFunction(data) {
        yourGlobalField = JSON.parse(data); //just assuming you receive a JSON object
        console.log("Value after update: ", yourGlobalField)
    }

    function networkError(err) {
        console.log('Request Failed', err);
    }
</script>
```